# Why does CFR 15 look so much different on eCFR vs the OLRC?

Tags: legislature, code-of-federal-regulations

Why does title 15 appear so substantially different (even the name of the title itself appears different) between the eCFR website the OLRC website?

OLRC, Cornell

http://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid%3AUSC-prelim-title15&saved=%7CZ3JhbnVsZWlkOlVTQy1wcmVsaW0tdGl0bGUxNS1jaGFwdGVyMi1zdWJjaGFwdGVyMQ%3D%3D%7C%7C%7C0%7Cfalse%7Cprelim&edition=prelim

https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15

eCFR, govinfo

https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-15

https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/cfr/2022/title15

Answer (score 5):

The first two links aren't the CFR, they are the USC, the United States Code.  This is a codification of statute law: laws enacted by Congress.  The last two links *are* to the CFR, the Code of Federal Regulations, which is the codification of regulations issued by the executive department.

They look different because they are different things.  Many of the titles correspond between the US Code and the CFR, but some are different.  Within titles that have the same number for the same topic, including title 15, the internal organization is often somewhat similar, but there usually is not direct correspondence.

Answer (score 1):

eCFR is an official government website. Cornell is a university's non-profit side project of some Cornell University law professors. Different IT teams are involved with different standards for formatting.

Comment: Have another look.  It's more than just different IT teams.

Comment: @phoog I was only trying to get at the differences between the CFR as shown at the Cornell website and eCFR. I agree with your answer that the Title 15 of the USC has substantive differences from the CFR.